# Why does adding a return value to my Python code stop it from printing?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-babel, python, pdf

Load up Emacs in the default modes, i.e. `emacs -Q`. After this, make a new .Org file with the following contents and run the Emacs Lisp code.

```lisp
(setq org-babel-python-command "python3")
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)

(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((python . t)))

#+PROPERTY: header-args :exports results :results output :eval yes

#+name: MyCosts
#+begin_src python
  per_year = 750 + 180 + 40
  print(per_year)
  #return 4
#+end_src
```

Following this, export the .Org file to PDF (`C-c C-e` followed by `l` and `o`). In the output, you will see that the value of `per-year` has printed but the return value of `4` has not. This is intended because the `return 4` is commented out by the `#`. However, if you remove the `#` and export to PDF again, both the `4` and the printed value of `per-year` disappear.

Why is this? Why does adding a return value disable printing? I see no errors in any relevant log.

Comment: There *is* an error: if you evaluate the block with `C-c C-c` it says: `File "<stdin>", line 3
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
[ Babel evaluation exited with code 1 ]`. If you change the `:results` header to `value` then the block is implicitly wrapped in a function, and the value of the block is `4`, but you lose stdout: it's discarded when `:results` is set to `value`.

Comment: See https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html

Comment: @NickD Huh. Wonder how I missed that. Feel free to submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you uncomment the `return` and try to export, there **is** an error: the error message is added to the `*Org-babel Error Output*` buffer and a diagnostic with the exit code (but not the error message(s)) is also sent with `message` to the echo area (which however may be overwritten quickly so you might not see it there) and to the `*Messages*` buffer. The `*Org-babel Error Output*` buffer should be displayed at the end of the evaluation if there is an error - and it does get displayed in my experiments.

The error message is:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 3
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
[ Babel evaluation exited with code 1 ]
```

The reason for the error message `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function` is obvious if you are using the Python interpreter from the command line: if you type the program in your code block verbatim into the interpreter, when you get to the `return 4` line, it is going to complain, printing out the error message to the standard error output, as programs are supposed to do on Unix/Linux:

```
$ python3
Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct  3 2023, 00:00:00) [GCC 13.2.1 20230728 (Red Hat 13.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> per_year = 1000
>>> print(per_year)
1000
>>> return  4
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
>>>
```

When Org-babel evaluates a code block, it accumulates the stuff that is printed to stdout and the stuff that is printed to stderr separately. The stderr stuff ends up in the `*Org-Babel Error Output*` buffer; the stdout stuff ends up as the result in your original buffer (or in the temporary buffer that is used when exporting), *provided* there is no error (if there is an error, the stdout stuff is discarded) *and* if the `:results` header is set to `output`.

That explains what happens in your two cases: if the `return` is commented out, there is no error and the stdout stuff (what you printed in your program without specifying where it's supposed to go) ends up as the result in your export *because* you have specified `:results output`. When you uncomment the `return 4` line, the python interpreter quits with an error, Org-babel uses the accumulated stderr stuff to populate the error buffer and discards the stdout stuff.

If in the latter case, you specify `:results value`, Org-babel's Python engine does a funky thing: it implicitly wraps your code block in a function and runs the function to get the result. That's why you don't get an error with the `return` (it is safely inside a function), but that also means that you cannot switch from `:results output` to `:results value` without changing your code. Also with `:results value`, the accumulated stdout stuff is discarded: it's the value that matters.

You can read about some or all of this in the [Python-specific Babel page](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html), although you might have to read between the lines to get some of it. In general, the [language-specific pages](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/) are necessary reading, *in addition to the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Working-with-Source-Code.html)*,which only covers the generic case.